# How can I make multiple script with chartjs?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want to make multiple scripts that one for chartjs chart and others for img src.
But when I use like this, html only represents chartjs not for img.
My purpose is to represent a image after chart.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    plugins:[ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
        labels: ['08/08',
                '08/09'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'ttt',
            data: [
            1304.1,
            1312.6
            ],
            fill:true,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(219, 68, 85, 1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(219, 68, 85, 0.4)"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive : true
            }
});
</script>
<script>
<img src="https://src.hidoc.co.kr/image/lib/2021/4/28/1619598179113_0.jpg" />
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you adding your image into a script tag? This is for JS not for HTML elements!

Comment: Then what tag should I use to add a image?

Comment: Just image inside your body.. Look at basic examples. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_alt_chania